# ($\sigma$-)completeness of Riesz spaces

Tags: reference-request, lattice-theory

Let $E$ be a Riesz space (or vector lattice). I am searching for examples (possibly with references) of especially $\sigma$-complete Riesz spaces (each countable set of positive elements has a greatest lower bound). If I am correct, there are no non-trivial complete Riesz spaces (each set of positive elements has a greatest lower bound) in the sense that only zero-dimensional Riesz spaces are complete. Can someone provide a proof or a reference for that fact? Typical examples I would like to see (of $\sigma$-complete Riesz spaces) are $\mathrm{L}^p$ for $0<p<\infty$, $\mathrm{Lip}$ or $\mathrm{C}(\mathbb{R})$. Is the space of all Baire funnctions $B([0,1])$ an example?